# Windows 8 Store App using HTML/WINJS winjs.ui.listview clustering data items

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

i have created a Winjs.UI.ListView(with Binging in GridViewtemplate: some images and titles)  and everything is OK But i would like de clustering(make groups of )my items close to each other and the others in the next Column of the listView .
I will be thinkful if anybody has an idea or some portion of code.

Comment: Are you trying to group items according to some specific property? A sketch of what you're trying to accomplish, or a screenshot of what you currently have vs. what you want might help us help you.

Comment: Problem solved , i must create another template for Group Header and binding it with the specific attribute .Thinks a lot devhammer

Comment: Glad you solved it, and glad to help!